# React App with PHP. Dockerfile implementation

Tags: php, html, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

I'm moving my app from Azure App Service to Azure Kubernetes Service and I need to dockerize it. It's a simple typescript/react app. I'd typically build and run it with the following sequence:

```
yarn
yarn staging
serve -s build -l 5000
```

However there is a little twist. I have a couple `php` pages that I need to support. How do I route all the traffic to `/index.html` except for the requests that land on `*.php` - those need to be processed as php scripts. Azure App Service would allow me to run my HTML5 app with PHP side by side. How do I achieve it with docker? What should my Dockerfile look like?

Here is what I came up with for now:

```
# Step 1
FROM node:10-alpine as build-step
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN yarn
RUN yarn staging

# Stage 2
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY --from=build-step /app/build /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

But this doesn't redirect to /index.html if I open http://example.com/non-existing-page.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the same container?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes I do. Please see my dockerfile as it is now

Comment: Having done a little research I am not sure that you can do this without it being really hacky. A better option might be another container that would run PHP scripts and return the results. Or use something like SupervisorD so you can run multiple services in the same container.

Comment: Could you please provide `docker ps` here?

Comment: You should build your static HTML page and not use serve directly, that is only for development, once you have your dist/build folder, you can serve it together with your PHP files, using the docker images for php-apache or php-fpm, otherwise you will require something like nginx to redirect everithing to the port you are serving and the php to the php executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the research I've managed to achieve the desired behaviour which is:

- Build react app with yarn
- Single Page Application URL rewriting
- Enabled PHP. I can open http://*.php webpagees
- Open /webpage and if there is webpage.php it would open php.

My final Dockerfile:

```
# Build
FROM node:10-alpine as build

ARG envType=staging

RUN echo ${envType}

RUN mkdir /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN yarn

RUN yarn ${envType}

# Run
FROM php:7.3-apache

COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www/html

RUN a2enmod rewrite

EXPOSE 80
```

And .htaccess file with rewrite rules:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```